# Restore of .bak file to a SharePoint 2007 Server results in 500 INTERNAL SERVER ERROR

Tags: 2007, restore

We have an old .bak file (1½ years) that we need to restore. The only change to the server is a couple of CU's otherwise it is like the server that the .bak file originated from (it's not the same, but we have been able to restore the .bak file before).

When we do the restore (stsadm) it chews on the file for a while (1.2GB) and says it's complete. It seems like the site has been made (through Central Admin) but whenever I try to access the site I get the "500 INTERNAL SERVER ERROR"

Any ideas how to gain access to the contents of this file, preferably including layout??? The final destination is SP2010 but it's ok if we can gain full access on SP2007

Kind regards,
noesgard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually we just solved it... The contents was visible through various tools, just not from the site.

This procedure made it available:

1. The backup file (.bak) is restored to a SP 2007 server (this does not make the content available)
2. Using Central Admin Create a new web application and crate a DB for that.
3. Run:  stsadm -o restore -url  -filename .bak.
4. Open the DB server and create a backup of the DB from 2).
5. Copy this backup to the SP 2010 SQL target server.
6. Restore the DB on the SQL Server from 6)
7. Create a new web application on target SP2010 frontend - create temporary DB
8. Run: stsadm -o addcontentdb -url  -databasename  -databaseserver >DB Server>
9. Remove the temporary DB from 8)

Answer (score 2):

I would remove the contentdb from SharePoint.  And then add the contentdb back using stsadm.  I think that might perform the upgrade needed.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263422(office.12).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the .NET version for a application pool in IIS to the earliest version, probably version 2.

Comment: Why would changing the .NET version on the app pool fix @noesgard's issue? I think it would be helpful if you include more information in your answer.